# Upload File to GraphQL from iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo-client, back4app

I am using Back4app backend for GraphQl and Apollo client for queries and mutations. Queries are fine, but i am unable to upload file to backend using perform mutation.

It says to perform mutation as FileInput , but I don’t know how to convert Uiimage to FileInput for writing to database. If I simply pass a string to FileInput, it is reaching database. But couldnot upload image.

Can someone give a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file to Parse using GraphQL by sending in a file with the `FileType` type, which has the `upload` property, which conforms to the Upload scaclar type.

A mutation for a class named Person, with a name (string), age (number) and photo (file), running on Parse 4.4 would look like this:

```
mutation createPerson{
  createPerson(input:{
    fields:{
      name: "Alex"
      age: 40
      photo: {
        upload: file
      }
    }
  }){
    person{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice that depending on the version of Parse that you are using, the syntax might be slightly different.

Also remember to pass the `file` as an upload as described here:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/mutations/#uploading-files

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that one Mutation you sent is that you try to set the image property as the $file, while you should set the upload like this:

```
mutation SingleFileUpload($file: Upload!,$filename: String!){
  createImages(input:{
    fields:{
      imagename: $filename
      image: {
          upload: $file
      }
    }
  }){
    images{
      imagename
      image{
        url
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: update former answer, don't post another one